# URL is appending if I click more than once

Tags: magento2.3, url, megamenu, customize, help-wanted

We have created megamenu for our site. But the issue we are facing is that the url is appending if click more than once instead of showing corresponding page.

How to resolve this issue?

Below is the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Top menu for store
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
 */
?>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('css/cart.css')?>">

  <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Top menu for store
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
 */
?>



<header class="headers">
  <div class="header-inrs">
    <div class="menu-container">
      <div class="menus contenedor-menu">
        <ul class="clearfix backcolor designmenu">
          <div class="totalmobilelog">
            <div class="lo">
              <a href="http://127.0.0.1/newmagento/customer/account/login/" ><b class="clsml">Login</b></a>
            </div>
            <div class="si">
              <a href="" ><b class="clsml">Sign Up</b></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php
          $categories = $block->getStoreCategories();

          foreach ($categories as $category):

          ?>


          <li><a href="<?php echo $category->getRequestPath();?>"><?php echo $category->getName(); ?>

            <?php
            $subCategories = $block->getCategoryById($category->getId());
            $subCats = $subCategories->getChildrenCategories();
            if(count($subCats) > 0): ?>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down arrowmm" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </a>
            <ul class="subc">
            <?php
            foreach ($subCats as $subCategory):
            ?>

            <li><a href="<?php echo $subCategory->getRequestPath();?>"><?php echo $subCategory->getName(); ?></a>

          </li>

          <?php endforeach; ?>

        </ul>
        <?php echo $block->getSubcategories($subCategories); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you please concat your category request path with base url and then check ? like **<a href="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().$category->getRequestPath();?>"><?php echo $category->getName(); ?>**

Comment: @KishanSavaliya, I have tried the code as you suggested but its not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You did that for both categories ? Child and Main category ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya, yes, I have done that for both main and sub categories

Comment: I've added answer, you can check there this may help you.

Comment: I have referred your answer still it doesn't work. When I use the code as in your answer, I can get the category page but the problem is appending.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the **`getRequestPath()`** with **`getUrl()`** to get the **category Url Path**.

Comment: I have tried with getUrl() and got the category page but the problem is appending the url. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please use **$category->getUrl()** and **$subCategory->getUrl()**.

This may be help you to get exact Category URL there.